# Sort LinkedHashMap by key and convert to List in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a HashMap like bellow:

```
{ 1 = "", 0 = Ecrivez, 2 = Hello }
```

I want to convert it into an ArrayList sorted by key like this:

```
Ecrivez, "", Hello
```

I used the following code but it doesn't work.

```
List sortedKeys = new ArrayList(testhmap.values());
Collections.sort(sortedKeys);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926218/sorting-arraylist-in-koltin-based-on-size check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this:

```
// Using TreeMap (Java 1.2+)
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(new TreeMap<>(map).values());
```

```
// Using Stream (Java 8+)
List<String> list = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByKey())
                    .map(Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Both of the above will turn map `{1=, 0=Ecrivez, 2=Hello}` into list `[Ecrivez, , Hello]`

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/z5GdG9).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    hashMap.put(1, "");
    hashMap.put(0, "Ecrivez");
    hashMap.put(2, "Hello");

    System.out.println("Before sort: " + hashMap.values());
    List<String> list = hashMap.keySet().stream().sorted().map(key -> hashMap.get(key))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("After sort: " + list);
  }
```

Output is as below:

```
Before sort: [, Ecrivez, Hello]
After sort: [Ecrivez, , Hello]
```